# Swagger breaking when inheriting from Base

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

Currently I'm using swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI 3.0 and I'm building my web api and in my controllers I'm inheriting from a base controller.

```
public class DocumentTypeController : BaseController<ObjectNameGoesHere>
{
    public DocumentTypeController(IRepository repository) : base(repository)
    {
         //In here I will just inherit from the methods from the 
         //BaseController
    }
}
```

All of the methods are in the BaseController which I can override. I get an error like this:

Fetch error: Internal Server Error /swagger/v1/swagger.json. Any ideas that may fix this issue?

```
public abstract class BaseController<T> : Controller where T : class, IEntity
{

    protected IRepository _repo;

    public BaseController(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repo = repository;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public virtual IQueryable<T> Get([FromServices] IQueryableRepository repository)
    {

        return repository.GetIQueryable<T>();

    }

    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    [Route("GetByID")]
    public async virtual Task<IActionResult> GetByIntID(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var data = await _repo.GetByIdAsync<T>(id);
            return Ok(data);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return BadRequest("Bad Request");
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    public async virtual Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] T dto)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _repo.Create<T>(dto);
                var result = await _repo.SaveAndReturnOneAsync(dto);
                return CreatedAtAction("GetByIntID", new { id = result.Id }, result);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Bad Request: Your data is incorrect");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return BadRequest("Bad Request: Item Not Added");
        }
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
    public async virtual Task<IActionResult> Put([FromBody] T dto)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _repo.Update<T>(dto);
                await _repo.SaveAsync();
                return Accepted();
            }

            else
            {
                return BadRequest("Bad Request: Your data is incorrect");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            return BadRequest("Bad Request: Item not Updated");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Internal Server Error => unhandled exception. Check the VIsual Studio Output window.

Comment: Try browsing to that file (/swagger/v1/swagger.json) it should have more info about your error

Comment: If you can share all your code with us, or create minimal project reproducing your issue

Comment: the swagger.json says: Ambiguous HTTP method for action - WebApi.Core.Controllers.DocumentTypeController.GetByIntID (WebApi.Core). Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger 2.0

Comment: look at this https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/581#issuecomment-235053027

Comment: try removing the [route] from the base class